# Не запускается приложение (Android)

Tags: android, apk

Не могу запустить приложение. Ни на реальном девайсе, ни на эмуляторе.

Проблема возникла после создания подписанного APK. При создании все прошло хорошо, ошибок не было. Потом внес изменения в код и запустил проверить на телефоне. Выдает следующую ошибку.

> Installation failed with message Failed to finalize session :
>   INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: /data/app/vmdl1623459420.tmp/4_slice__
>   signatures are inconsistent. It is possible that this issue is
>   resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is
>   present, and then re-installing.
>
> WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!
>
> Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

Удаление последней версии приложения с телефона с повторным запуском не помогло. Старая версия удалилась, новая не устанавливается. Подскажите что делать.

**Дополнительно:**
Работаю в Android Studio 2.3, операционная система Windows 10.

Помимо формирования подписанного apk, так же настраивал автоматическое подписание в проекте. Потом все удалил - не помогло. Еще пробовал пересоздавать подписанный apk, тоже не помогло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Странно, но помогло удаление созданного apk и rebuild + clean project.
При повторном создании подписанного apk никаких ошибок при запуске приложения не возникло.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте взять неподписанный APK (можно удалить папку META-INF из подписанного), и подписать такой командой:

```
jarsigner -verbose -keystore %USERPROFILE%/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android -digestalg SHA1 -sigalg MD5withRSA -sigfile CERT youapk.apk androiddebugkey
```

Пароли и т.д. поправьте, если изменяли.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Проблема решилась немного по другому.